# What may be the cause of the error "ReferenceError: Velocity is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

help please help, I do not understand the reason. Throws an error ReferenceError: Velocity is not defined. If I use $ (function () {}; then the error disappears, but then simply do not work. Use hammer 2.0.4 and velocity 1.2.3

```js
// Constants
const THRESH = 0.75;
const TIMING = 250;

// When the dom is loaded, set up hammer events.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', f => {
  var lis = document.querySelectorAll('.swipe');
  for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    let hammertime = new Hammer(lis[i]);
    hammertime.on('panright', e => handlePan(e));
    hammertime.on('panend', e => reset(e));
  }
});

// pane{right} handler
function handlePan(e, model) {
  var {target: el, deltaX: dx} = e;
  if (doAction(dx, el)) {
    el.classList.add('action');
  } else {
    el.classList.remove('action');
  }
  Velocity(el, {
    translateX: dx
  }, 0);
}

// panend handler
function reset(e) {
  var {target: el, deltaX: dx} = e;
  // Should we remove the element?
  if (doAction(dx, el)) {
    Velocity(el, {
      translateX: dx * 2
    }, TIMING).then(() => {
      return Velocity(el, {
        height: 0
      }, TIMING);
    }).then(() => {
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    });
  } else {
    Velocity(el, {
      translateX: 0
    }, TIMING);
  }
}

// Determines if an element will be dismissed
function doAction(dx, el) {
  return Math.abs(dx) >= THRESH * el.clientWidth;
}
```

```css
.swipe {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #9e9e9e;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  width: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="swipe">Swipe me!</div>


<!--Scripts-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.4/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see you defining `Velocity` anywhere, or constructing it.

Comment: Please show us the HTML, it's possible that you simply included the JS files in the wrong order, but we'd need to see your HTML to know for sure.

Comment: pardon, I added to the  question.

Comment: You may need to move your external script references up to the top of the page (in the HEAD section) or, at least move velocity.min.js BEFORE hammer.min.js.

Comment: I apologize. It helped. Moved velotsity end Hammer  in the HEAD section. jquery left in place.And do not tell me why? And if you can not do that worked in my original script sequence alignment? Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

> The `velocity` library reference should have been **BEFORE** the
>   jQuery reference. The way you know this is that when you run the code, with the developers tools open (F12) and you get the error, the error comes up from within the jQuery code - - so that means that jQuery can't find velocity. Then looking at the script references, you can see why...the jQuery library is running before the velocity library has been loaded.

This works:

```js
// Constants
const THRESH = 0.75;
const TIMING = 250;

// When the dom is loaded, set up hammer events.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', f => {
  var lis = document.querySelectorAll('.swipe');
  for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    let hammertime = new Hammer(lis[i]);
    hammertime.on('panright', e => handlePan(e));
    hammertime.on('panend', e => reset(e));
  }
});

// pane{right} handler
function handlePan(e, model) {
  var {target: el, deltaX: dx} = e;
  if (doAction(dx, el)) {
    el.classList.add('action');
  } else {
    el.classList.remove('action');
  }
  Velocity(el, {
    translateX: dx
  }, 0);
}

// panend handler
function reset(e) {
  var {target: el, deltaX: dx} = e;
  // Should we remove the element?
  if (doAction(dx, el)) {
    Velocity(el, {
      translateX: dx * 2
    }, TIMING).then(() => {
      return Velocity(el, {
        height: 0
      }, TIMING);
    }).then(() => {
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    });
  } else {
    Velocity(el, {
      translateX: 0
    }, TIMING);
  }
}

// Determines if an element will be dismissed
function doAction(dx, el) {
  return Math.abs(dx) >= THRESH * el.clientWidth;
}
```

```css
.swipe {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #9e9e9e;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  width: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<!--Scripts-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.4/hammer.min.js"></script>

<div class="swipe">Swipe me!</div>
```